# Botão Next e Previous para Slider

Tags: slide

Tenho esse código, onde o slide passa adiante automaticamente conforme o timer definido.
Como posso implementar um botão Next e Previous?

```
$("#image-vitrine > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function slideVitrine() {
    $('#image-vitrine > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .hide()
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#image-vitrine');
}, 6500);
```

Comment: Ao meu ver, você poderia utilizar esse mesmo código, separando-o em uma função e assim como você chama no setInterval, você poderia chamar executando o click do botão, isso não seria viável? Se quiser colocar mais informações do código para que possa te orientar melhor...

Comment: Luis, a única informação a mais é o html.
Tem a div #image-vitrine e abaixo dela outra div com <img>